# Richfaces 4.3 action in rich:commandButtom submit when page is loading

Tags: java, maven, richfaces, facelets

I'm trying to write a  project with EJB, JSF, and Maven and facelets
the problem is when I call the page in the browser, the action parameter submits the form (without click)

The xhtml page loads and not the action of my rich: commandbuttom already runs (calls the bean's method)!
does forgot to configure something?

If someone can give me a light, I am sending my pom.xml and part of my screen (xhtml).

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"


xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>projecto.com.br</groupId>
  <artifactId>PortalScheduler</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>APP Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Draft-16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Alpha1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Beta2</version>
    </dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-excelant</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Alpha2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0.Beta2</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>axis</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime.3_7_1</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.wsdl</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
    <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>axis</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis-saaj</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0-5</version>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api-libs</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>xstream</groupId>
    <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4c</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ant</groupId>
    <artifactId>ant-javamail</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.retrotranslator</groupId>
    <artifactId>retrotranslator-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ant</groupId>
    <artifactId>ant-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-core-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-components-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
</dependency>


</dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>InterService</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Part of my xtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
        xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
        xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
        >
<h:body>
<ui:composition template="template/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">

     <table class="table table-bordered">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>Data Cadastro</th>
                                        <th>Status</th> 
                                        <th>Arquivo</th>
                                        <th>Processar</th>
                                        <th>Progress</th>
                                         <th>%</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <ui:repeat value="#{especialistaAtualizaBlacklist.arquivosBlacklist}" var="item">
                                     <h:form id="form1">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><h:outputLabel value="#{item.cd_repositorio}" /></td>

                                        <td><h:outputLabel value="#{item.dt_cadastro}" /></td>

                                        <td>                                 
                                            <h:outputText value="Processado" class="label label-success " rendered="#{item.ic_processado==1}" />
                                            <h:outputText value="Pendente" class="label label-warning " rendered="#{item.ic_processado==0}" />                                           
                                        </td>






                                        <td><h:outputLabel value="#{item.nm_arquivo}" /></td>

                                        <td>

                                            <rich:commandLink type="button" value="Processar Agora" rendered="#{item.ic_processado==0}"  id="btnProcessar" action="#{especialistaAtualizaBlacklist.doExecuta(item.cd_repositorio)}"  styleClass="btn btn-info btn-sm"  /> 



                                       </td>
                                          <td>
                                            <div class="progress xs progress-striped active">

                                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 100%"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>                                            
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="badge bg-red">
                                                <a4j:outputPanel id="outputProgesso" ajaxRendered="true">
                                                    <h:outputText value="#{especialistaAtualizaBlacklist.progresso} %"   rendered="#{item.ic_processado==0}" />
                                                    <h:outputText value="100%"   rendered="#{item.ic_processado==1}"/>
                                                </a4j:outputPanel>
                                            </span>
                                        </td> 


                                    </tr>
                                    </h:form>
                                    </ui:repeat>


                                </table>    


    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>


        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="../../js/AdminLTE/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
    <script src="../../js/AdminLTE/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
@Stateless
public class EspecialistaAtualizaBlacklist {
public EspecialistaAtualizaBlacklist() {
    }
    @Schedule(dayOfWeek = "Mon-Fri", hour = "*/1", persistent = false)
    public void executaScheduler() throws IOException {
    //do something
    }   
    public void doExecuta(Long cd_repositorio){
        System.out.println("WOW! "+cd_repositorio);
    }   
}
```

any erros in logs.
thank you .

Comment: What version of JSF are you using? What packages are you importing your JSF annotations from? Also, it's not really a good idea to have your JSF managed bean doubling as an EJB